Copy values to worksheet table from every third textbox on a userform with dymamically populated textboxes
I have a workbook that is supposed to rename all the files in a folder selected by a user. The user enters a folder path for the files to be renamed and a desired location for the renamed files. A user form (called UserForm1) then opens with a dynamic list of text boxes. The user form always has three columns: "File Name," "Old File Path," and "New File Name." When UserForm1 opens, the number of rows of text boxes will equal the number of files in the current file location. I am able to generate this user form with the code below:
    Option Explicit

    Const NameCol = 1
    Const LocCol = 2
    Const NewNameCol = 3
    Const NewFileLoc = 4

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim row As Range

        For Each row In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FT_Setup").Rows
           If row.Cells(2, 1).Value = "" Then
              Exit For
           End If
           Call AddBox(row.Offset(1, 0), NameCol)
           Call AddBox(row.Offset(1, 0), LocCol)
           Call AddBox(row.Offset(1, 0), NewNameCol)
        Next row
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddBox(row, colIndex)
        Dim box As Control
        Dim width As Integer
        Dim padwidth As Integer
        Dim leftMargin As Integer
        Dim topMargin As Integer
    
        Const height = 15
        Const padHeight = height + 4

        With Me.Frame1.Controls

        If colIndex = 1 Then
           width = 100
           padwidth = width + 4
           topMargin = 1
           leftMargin = 5
    
           Set box = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", row.row & colIndex)
           box.Left = (colIndex - 1) * padwidth + leftMargin
           box.height = height
           box.width = width
           box.Top = (row.row) * padHeight + topMargin
           box.Value = row.Cells(1, colIndex).Value
        ElseIf colIndex = 2 Then
           width = 140
           padwidth = width + 4
           topMargin = 1
           leftMargin = -35
    
           Set box = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", row.row & colIndex)
           box.Left = (colIndex - 1) * padwidth + leftMargin
           box.height = height
           box.width = width + 125
           box.Top = (row.row) * padHeight + topMargin
           box.Value = row.Cells(1, colIndex).Value

        ElseIf colIndex = 3 Then
           width = 203
           padwidth = width + 4
           topMargin = 1
           leftMargin = -35
    
           Set box = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1", row.row & colIndex)
           box.Left = (colIndex - 1) * padwidth + leftMargin
           box.height = height
           box.width = width * 0.5
           box.Top = (row.row) * padHeight + topMargin
           box.Value = row.Cells(1, colIndex).Value
        End If
        End With
   End Sub

The first two columns of the userform are to be noneditable. Said another way, I am only allowing the user to edit every third textbox, which will then be copied to a column in a table on a worksheet. This now leads to my two questions:

How do I dynamically generate the same list of textboxes, but with the first two columns generated as noneditable textboxes?

Knowing that i am generating a dynamic list of textboses, how do I copy values from every third text box in the userform (just the third editable column) to a table column on the worksheet? The below code is what i am having trouble with. it only copy's the very last textbox value too all rows under the desired table column on the worksheet.
Private Sub bttnSaveClose_Click()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim ctrl As Control
  Dim i As Integer

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("locations")

 lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
      For i = 2 To lastRow
         ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = ctrl.Value
      Next i
    End If
 next ctrl

 UserForm1.Hide
 End Sub



